# CAKEPHP foreign key restraint - Debug shows correct values

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys

I am creating my first real CakePHP project.  I have read the manual and gone through the blog tutorial, but am by no means an expert.  I'm having a problem adding data to my database through a form generated with the form helper.  The form has two text inputs and a few select boxes, all of which are populating correctly.  When I fill out the form and hit submit, it tells me I have a foreign key constraint error on the first select box.  However, when I debug $this->request->data, it has the correct values associated with it.  Here is the debug.

```
Array
(
    [car] => Array
        (
        [stock] => G123456
        [vin] => 12345678
        [make_id] => 1
        [car_model_id] => 2
        [year_id] => 20
        [location_id] => 9
        [service_status_id] => 1
        [type_id] => 6
        )

)
```

To make sure my schema was correct I did the insert directly from mysql console and it worked perfectly.  Here is the command I ran.

```
INSERT INTO cars (stock, vin, make_id, car_model_id, year_id, location_id, service_status_id, type_id) VALUES ('G123456', '12345678', '1', '2', '20', '9', '1', '6');
```

I'm not sure why it's giving me the foreign key constraint error when I call:

```
$car = $this->Car->save($this->request->data);
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**  The query under the error in CakePHP is:

```
INSERT INTO `cars` (`modified`, `created`) VALUES ('2012-02-29 15:53:21', '2012-02-29 15:53:21')
```

When I run that query from a mysql console I get the same error.  Foreign key constraint fails, make_id - reference make.id

Here is the add() function in my controller:

```
public function add()
{   
    $this->set('years', $this->Car->Year->find('list'));
    $this->set('makes', $this->Car->Make->find('list'));
    $this->set('carModels', $this->Car->CarModel->find('list'));
    $this->set('locations', $this->Car->Location->find('list'));
    $this->set('types', $this->Car->Type->find('list'));
    $this->set('serviceStatuses', $this->Car->ServiceStatus->find('list'));
    if(!empty($this->request->data))
    {
        $car = $this->Car->save($this->request->data);  
        //debug($this->request->data, true);
    }
}
```

And here is the view file:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Car', array('action' => 'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('car.stock');
echo $this->Form->input('car.vin');
echo $this->Form->input('car.make_id');
echo $this->Form->input('car.car_model_id');
echo $this->Form->input('car.year_id');
echo $this->Form->input('car.location_id');
echo $this->Form->input('car.service_status_id');
echo $this->Form->input('car.type_id');
echo $this->Form->end('Add');
?>
```

Comment: This query was that you have created manually or you got the error that was displayed on the screen? You can expand the errors generated on the screen to check the SQL syntax generated.

Comment: When I run the query manually I it works fine.  When I issue $car = $this->Car->save($this->request->data) I get the foreign key constraint error on make_id.  The query that shows up in the error in Cake right below the error is:
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `cars` (`modified`, `created`) VALUES ('2012-02-29 15:53:21', '2012-02-29 15:53:21')

Comment: So, that's the problem, the query is being generated wrong, missing the other fields. Can you update your question em post how do you created form?

Comment: Shouldn't the `car` key on your data array be `Car`, with an uppercase `C`?

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, I think you're right.  I'm not sure how to make it capitalized though.  I tried to change my input forms to Car.fieldname instead of car.fieldname, but the key is still lowercase.  How do I change it?

Comment: @Stewie, you might have a lowercase `car` on `$this->Form->create('car');` too.

Comment: Nope, you were correct.  I never refreshed the page so it was sending car still instead of Car after I changed the model name in my form inputs.  

So I was using modelname.fieldname rather than Modelname.fieldname.  That resolved the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Note, you do not need to put the class name when the fields refer to the class itself. Can use `$this->Form->input('stock')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the view. Remove the `car.` from the beginning of each form input. It is not needed. The create will user the `Car` model as the prefix and it will fix the problem.

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Car', array('action' => 'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('stock');
echo $this->Form->input('vin');
echo $this->Form->input('make_id');
echo $this->Form->input('car_model_id');
echo $this->Form->input('year_id');
echo $this->Form->input('location_id');
echo $this->Form->input('service_status_id');
echo $this->Form->input('type_id');
echo $this->Form->end('Add');
?>
```